# How to layout a photo text grid side by side

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm looking for some help to get the layout seen in the mockup. I'd like a 3x2 grid of text image, image text, text image that stacks on mobile. Each of the images need to be touching diagonally. What would be the best way of achieving this?
Mockup

[image]
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There's a couple of ways of doing this. My solution involves the use of CSS Grid, which is a very clean approach (with the caveat that IE11 needs a little more handholding).

The following snippet has a breakpoint for desktop size to show the two columns, anything below that is stacked.

HTML

```
<article>
    <div class="text">Text
    </div>
    <div class="image">Image
    </div>
    <div class="text">Text
    </div>
    <div class="image">Image
    </div>
    <div class="text">Text
    </div>
    <div class="image">Image
    </div>
</article>
```

CSS

```
article {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: 1;
    grid-auto-rows: minmax(100px, auto);
    background: grey;
}
.image,
.text {
    background: red;
    height: 100px;
}
.image {
    background: green;
}
.text:nth-of-type(3) {
    background: magenta;
}
.image:nth-of-type(4) {
    background: blue;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 1025px) {
    article {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        background: grey;
    }
    .text:nth-of-type(3) {
        grid-column: 2;
        grid-row: 2;
    }
}
```

Codepen

https://codepen.io/sassquad/pen/ooLEOa

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I'll try and get this working in IE